# PHP resize image from curl in memory

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to resize an image I'm getting from a Curl request, but I don't want to save it to a file in order to resize it. This is what I'm trying, but not working:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remote_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$picture = curl_exec($ch);
$contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
curl_close($ch);

// And then to resize $picture
$data = htmlspecialchars($picture, ENT_QUOTES);
$data = base64_decode($data);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data); 
$imaget1 = imagescale($im, $maxsize);
```

Answer (score 1):

What worked was this to resize $picture:

```
$image = 'data://application/octet-stream;base64,' . base64_encode($picture);

$mime = getimagesize($image);

if($mime['mime'] == 'image/jpeg'){ $imagecreated = imagecreatefromjpeg($image); }
if($mime['mime'] == 'image/jpg'){ $imagecreated = imagecreatefromjpeg($image); }
if($mime['mime'] == 'image/png'){ $imagecreated = imagecreatefrompng($image); }
if($mime['mime'] == 'image/gif'){ $imagecreated = imagecreatefromgif($image); }
$imageScaled = imagescale($imagecreated, $maxsize);

ob_start ();
if($mime['mime'] == 'image/jpeg'){ imagejpeg($imageScaled, null, $quality); }
if($mime['mime'] == 'image/jpg'){ imagejpeg($imageScaled, null, $quality); }
if($mime['mime'] == 'image/png'){ imagepng($imageScaled, null, "8"); }
if($mime['mime'] == 'image/gif'){ imagegif($imageScaled, null, $quality); }
$image = ob_get_contents ();
ob_end_clean ();

imagedestroy($imagecreated);

return $image;
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed it around a little bit and used it in this way:

```
    // --Take in curl data image and return base64 text image resized --
    private function GenBase64Thumb($curl_image_data, $maxsize = 300, $quality = 85) {

    $image = 'data://application/octet-stream;base64,' . base64_encode($curl_image_data);
    $imagecreated = null;
    $mime = getimagesize($image);

    switch ($mime['mime']) {
      case 'image/jpeg':
      case 'image/jpg':
        $imagecreated = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);
        break;
      case 'image/png':
        $imagecreated = imagecreatefrompng($image);
        break;
      case 'image/gif':
        $imagecreated = imagecreatefromgif($image);
        break;
      default:
        return null;
    }

    if (!empty($imagecreated) && $imageScaled = imagescale($imagecreated, $maxsize)) {
      ob_start();
      switch ($mime['mime']) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
        case 'image/jpg':
          imagejpeg($imageScaled, NULL, $quality);
          break;
        case 'image/png':
          imagepng($imageScaled, NULL, "8");
          break;
        case 'image/gif':
          imagegif($imageScaled, NULL, $quality);
          break;
        default:
          return null;
      }
      $image = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();
      imagedestroy($imagecreated);
      return !empty($image) ? base64_encode($image) : null;
    }
    return null;
  }
```